# Open CV traincascade gets stuck with a Hit rate of 1 and a False alarm rate of 0

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I want to train a LBP classifier.  I have 103 positive and 500 negative samples.  I used almost default values, except for `-featureType LBP` and `-numPos 88`.

```
opencv_traincascade -data "$NAME"_Output \
                    -vec "$NAME".vec \
                    -bg "$NAME"_Negative.txt \
                    -numPos 88 \
                    -numNeg 500 \
                    -numStages 20 \
                    -stageType BOOST \
                    -featureType LBP \
                    -w 32 \
                    -h 48 \
                    -bt GAB \
                    -minHitRate 0.995 \
                    -maxFalseAlarmRate 0.5 \
                    -weightTrimRate 0.95 \
                    -maxDepth 1 \
                    -maxWeakCount 100
```

The classifier gets stuck at stage 2 after stage 1 got a full hit rate and a zero false alarm rate.  I tried playing with the numPos, numNeg, and bt parameters, but it always gets approximately the same result.

```
===== TRAINING 0-stage =====
<BEGIN
POS count : consumed   88 : 88
NEG count : acceptanceRatio    500 : 1
Precalculation time: 1
+----+---------+---------+
|  N |    HR   |    FA   |
+----+---------+---------+
|   1|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   2|        1|    0.046|
+----+---------+---------+
END>

===== TRAINING 1-stage =====
<BEGIN
POS count : consumed   88 : 88
NEG count : acceptanceRatio    500 : 0.0456038
Precalculation time: 0
+----+---------+---------+
|  N |    HR   |    FA   |
+----+---------+---------+
|   1|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   2|        1|        0|
+----+---------+---------+
END>

===== TRAINING 2-stage =====
<BEGIN
POS count : consumed   88 : 88
```

I don't know enough about this but my guess is that its complete after stage 1, but it still trying to generate 18 more stages.  My data set is quite simple,  the positive should all be quite similar and the negative images are the same size.

- Is it possible to have a classifier with only 2 stages? (stage 0 and stage 1)
- Has anyone got a LBP classifier working before, or should I stick to HAAR?
- Have I made any mistakes with the parameters or input data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your training data. If its really simple to discriminate positive and negative data, then its quite possible that two stages are enough to do the job. The question now is, how it performs on test data, i.e., is your training data representative for the test, or do you need more (and more complicated) training samples. If not, you're done. congrats.

Comment: Yes - my data is quite simple. I was thinking that it might be trained ok with just 2 stages, but I wants confident enough in Open cv to know for sure if that was the case or if it had broken.  Its frustrating that the program didn't recognise that it was done.  Thank you for the answer :)